# Menu Header I have not chosen?

Tags: html, wordpress, menu, header

my site is http://craiccon.ie/

I want the menu header to be 
Tickets
What’s CraicCon?
CraicCon 2016
Facebook
Twitter

and for some reason I'm getting random unchosen menu choices as well as the ones I want? Can anyone help?

Comment: Hammm. Is you select menu from setting->menu

Comment: @SajidAnwar nope thats not it.

Comment: Then what do you mean. Sorry if you explain me i can slove your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the menu correctly, except it's missing Twitter at the end. Is it stuck in the cache on your end?